# how to edit memory using CreateFileMappingA in windows

Tags: c, windows, winapi, msdn

I have existing file, I want to open that file and map using mapping and edit particular field with some value and create new file. But value is not changing original value is retaining.

Open existing file:

```
File = CreateFileA(PathFile, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0,
    NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
```

Create file mapping:

```
FileMap = CreateFileMappingA(File, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, 0, NULL);
```

Map View of file:

```
ViewBase = MapViewOfFile(FileMap, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, 0);
```

Chaging value at particular location:

```
LocalViewBase= (_DUMP_HEADER64*)ViewBase;
LocalViewBase->DumpType = 0; //for example 1 is replaced with 0
```

New File copying same contents after modifying particual value DumpType:

```
count = fwrite(ViewBase, 1, sizeofdata, dumpfile);
```

In dumpfile after above copy orginal value rained new file creation.

Comment: Rather than describing individual lines of code, can you put together a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem in action? You say the new file is not getting the new data, does the original file get the new data after you close the mapping/view, or at least flush the file buffers?

Comment: Sure I will update minimal reproduction code. Either of the file is not updated with new value after closing mapping and view. I FlushViewOfFile I tried after updating value and before closing handles. Original file I don’t want to change but want Create copy of file with some values need to edit before creating new file.

Comment: "*Original file I don’t want to change*" - then you CAN'T use a memory-mapped view of the original file the way you are attempting to, as changing any data through such a view WILL change the original file! For what you are asking for, you are just going to have to actually read the original file into a separate memory buffer that you allocate, and then you can modify and save that buffer as you want. Or, you can make an unmodified copy of the original file first, then memory-map the copied file and modify its data through a view.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks by proper unmap fileview able to reflect the data.

Comment: [UnmapViewOfFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-unmapviewoffile#remarks) will write modified pages to disk later. *File mapping* is **the association** of a file's contents with a portion of the virtual address space of a process. See [File Mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/file-mapping) for more information.